# Help with accessing nextcloud instance from web browser by using domain name

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, nextcloud

Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Nextcloud Version: nextcloud 23.0.0

Apache version: 2.4.41

I am trying to setup a nextcloud instance on my linux server. However when i try to access it from the web browser(firefox) by typing server.swayamshree.com I am getting the message:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at server.swayamshree.com Port 80

Any help will be deeply appreciated. I have listed the details of my configuration below.

The folder for my nextcloud instance is located at /media/swayam/external/server.swayamshree.com with the following permissions:

> drwxr-xr-x 13 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 26 15:54 server.swayamshree.com

The file located at /etc/apache2/sites-available/server/swayamshree.com.conf has the following content:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot "/media/swayam/external/server.swayamshree.com"
 ServerName server.swayamshree.com

 <Directory "/media/swayam/external/server.swayamshree.com/">
     Options MultiViews FollowSymlinks
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Require all granted
 </Directory>

 TransferLog /var/log/apache2/server.swayamshree.com_access.log
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/server.swayamshree.com_error.log
 </VirtualHost>
```

The appropriate content of the file located at /etc/apache2/apache2.conf is as follows:

```
...
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /media/swayam/external/server.swayamshree.com/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache, by default, is limited to the `/var/www` directory. As a result, you have two options to choose from:

1. Create a mount point for your NextCloud installation that exists inside `/var/www`
2. Modify the AppArmor profile, which limits Apache to the one directory, to allow read/write access to the external location

Both of these options are perfectly valid, though the first may be simpler.

Comment: Tried doing option 1. I am still getting the same error